# How to urldecode PHP Laravel or PHP Lumen route query parameter?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, lumen

English characters work when I pass it as query parameter but not Arabic characters.

This works:

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/terms/search/found`

Terminal Log:

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/terms/search/found`

This does not:

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/terms/search/حو`

Terminal Log:

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/terms/search/%D8%AD%D9%88`

PHP Route:

```
$router->group(['prefix' => 'terms'], function () use ($router) {
    $router->get('', 'TermController@index');
    $router->get('/search/{term}', 'TermController@search');
});
```

How can I use `urldecode` PHP method on the route or is there any workaround for this situation?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why terminal does not display characters but the following fixed getting data from database:

Set the following in environment for the database:

```
DB_CHARSET=utf8
DB_COLLATION=utf8_unicode_ci
```